# Limit - Applicability of L'Hopital's Rule:$\lim\limits_{x \to 0^+} \frac{xe^x}{e^x-1}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

I am required to find $\lim\limits_{x \to 0^+} \frac{xe^x}{e^x-1}$.

---

My attempt:

$\lim\limits_{x \to 0^+} \frac{xe^x}{e^x-1}$ = $\lim\limits_{x \to 0^+} e^x$ $\cdot$ $\lim\limits_{x \to 0^+} \frac{x}{e^x-1}$

$=1\cdot\lim\limits_{x \to 0^+} \frac{x}{e^x-1}$

$=\lim\limits_{x \to 0^+} e^{-x}$ (L'Hopital's Rule)

$= 1$ (which is the correct answer)

---

My **question** is: Why am I not able to apply the rule to the equation right from the beginning [since substituting $0$ we get $\frac{0}{0}$]?

$\lim\limits_{x \to 0^+} \frac{xe^x}{e^x-1}$

$=\lim\limits_{x \to 0^+} \frac{xe^x}{e^x}$

$=\lim\limits_{x \to 0^+}x$

$=0$ (wrong)

Comment: It is applicable, you're just computing the derivative wrong.

$$(xe^x)^\prime = xe^x + e^x.$$

Comment: But why use L'Hopital's rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to apply L'Hospital's rule right from the beginning, you may write
$$
\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{x \to 0^+}\frac{xe^x}{e^x-1}&=\lim\limits_{x \to 0^+}\frac{e^x+xe^x}{e^x}=\frac{1+0}1=1
\end{align}
$$ since
$$
(xe^x)'=e^x+xe^x.
$$